# Display poster image again after video plays using jwplayer + HTML5

Tags: html, html5-video, jwplayer

How can i display again the poster image after the end of my video using jwplayer? Here's a code snippet:

```
<video
    src="video/Motion.mp4"
    height="860"
    id="video"
    width="620"
    poster="img/poster.png"
    onclick="play();">
    </video>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    jwplayer("video").setup({
    flashplayer: "jwplayer/player.swf",
    controlbar: "none",
    });

    jwplayer().getPlugin("display").hide();
    </script>
```

Comment: does the poster image work for you at all?  I see the jwplayer demo uses "image=" and which automagically reappears after the vid is complete.

Comment: yes it displays at first. But after the video play it goes to share tab

Comment: Just figured it out. I should download the jwplayer without the viral share

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried leveraging the onComplete event?

http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/jw-player-for-flash-v5/12540/javascript-api-reference#Events

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jwplayer("video").setup({
  flashplayer: "jwplayer/player.swf",
  controlbar: "none",
  events: {
    onComplete: function() {
      alert('video has finished..do something here..');
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: ok what should be inside onComplete? because right now the video goes to share etc after it plays

Comment: just figure it out, i should download the version of jwplayer without the viral share